# not able to get nested json value as column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create schema for json, and see it as columns in dataframe

Input json

```
{"place":{"place_name":"NYC","lon":0,"lat":0,"place_id":1009}, "region":{"region_issues":[{"key":"health","issue_name":"Cancer"},{"key":"sports","issue_name":"swimming"}}}
```

code

```
  val schemaRsvp =  new StructType()
      .add("place",  StructType(Array(
      StructField("place_name", DataTypes.StringType),
      StructField("lon", DataTypes.IntegerType),
      StructField("lat", DataTypes.IntegerType),
      StructField("place_id", DataTypes.IntegerType))))

 val ip =  spark.read.schema(schemaRsvp).json("D:\\Data\\rsvp\\inputrsvp.json")
 ip.show()
```

Its showing all the fields in single column `place`, want values column wise

```
place_name,lon,lat,place_id
NYC,0,0,1009
```

Any suggestion, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert struct type into columns using ".*"

```
ip.select("place.*").show()

+----------+---+---+--------+
|place_name|lon|lat|place_id|
+----------+---+---+--------+
|       NYC|  0|  0|    1009|
+----------+---+---+--------+
```

**UPDATE:**

with the new column array you can explode your date and then do the same ".*" to convert struct type into columns:

```
ip.select(col("place"), explode(col("region.region_issues")).as("region_issues"))
  .select("place.*", "region_issues.*").show(false)

+---+---+--------+----------+----------+------+
|lat|lon|place_id|place_name|issue_name|key   |
+---+---+--------+----------+----------+------+
|0  |0  |1009    |NYC       |Cancer    |health|
|0  |0  |1009    |NYC       |swimming  |sports|
+---+---+--------+----------+----------+------+
```

Comment: thanks, updated my json a bit, it has array of values too for region_issues element, how can I get those values too ?